# How to select table's tr second td value get in angular 6

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

Tried to get table's tr second td value but not working.I think closest is not working in angular 6.Can we write any other method for angular 6.If anyone know please help to find the solution.

```
  let target = e.originalEvent.toElement.closest('tr');
        if (target && target.id) {
            let td = target.querySelector('td:nth-child(2)');
            if (td) {
                 console.log("This row ID value is ="+ td.value )
            }  
  }
```

Comment: can you post the component template and class files ?

Comment: is this `e.originalEvent.toElement` return correct element ?

Comment: @AmarSingh:: Yes..e.originalEvent.toElement is return correct but i want to catch closest tr

Comment: e is dropdown onchange event

Comment: What do you get when you console `target `

Comment: getting like closest is undefined function